# Spied function is not called

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have an if condition inside a function as given below

```
 public setOption() {
    setTimeout(() => {
    if (this.isCMode && !this.quest['isCompleted']) {
        this.toggleOption(false);
      }
},window['TIME_OUT']);
```

so to test the above  function i was trying to write a jasmine test case ,as below

```
it('should call toggleOption from setSaqOption if isTimeCompleted is false', () => {
    component.isCMode = true;
    const tSpy = spyOn<any>(component, 'toggleOption');
    component.setOption();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      if (component.isCMode && !component.quest['isTimeCompleted']) {
        expect(tSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
      }
    });

  });
```

but whenever i run the test case it fails and says Expected spy toggleOption to have been called,where is that i'm going wrong if any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

use `fakeAsync()` and `tick()` to simulate time in the test - a `tick()` will resolve the `setTimeout` in the original `setOption()`, and the check could happen right after in a `fixture.whenStable().then(...)`

E.g.

`example.component.ts`:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

window['TIME_OUT'] = 1000;

@Component({})
export class ExampleComponent {
  isCMode = false;
  quest = {
    isCompleted: false,
    isTimeCompleted: false,
  };
  public setOption() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.isCMode && !this.quest['isCompleted']) {
        this.toggleOption(false);
      }
    }, window['TIME_OUT']);
  }
  toggleOption(flag) {}
}
```

`example.component.spec.ts`:

```js
import {
  ComponentFixture,
  fakeAsync,
  TestBed,
  tick,
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ExampleComponent } from './example.component';

fdescribe('65197197', () => {
  let component: ExampleComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ExampleComponent>;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ExampleComponent],
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ExampleComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });
  it('should call toggleOption from setSaqOption if isTimeCompleted is false', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.isCMode = true;
    const tSpy = spyOn<any>(component, 'toggleOption');
    component.setOption();
    tick(1000);
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      if (component.isCMode && !component.quest['isTimeCompleted']) {
        expect(tSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
      }
    });
  }));
});
```

unit test result:

[image]